# Laravel - How to add where clause to Eloquent Top 5 Query

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel-5.8 Eloquent Query as shown below:

```
   $destination = Trip::select('destination')
      ->selectRaw('COUNT(*) AS count')
      ->groupBy('destination')
      ->orderByDesc('count')
      ->limit(5)
      ->get();
```

How do I include this in the query above?

> where client_id = $userClientId

Comment: In `trip` schema is does exist `client_id` ?

Comment: Simply use 'where'. What is the issue with 'where' clause here?

Comment: Trip::where('client_id', $userClientId)

Comment: @Rashed Hasan - Yes, client_id exist in Trip

Comment: hmm, then @Franz is correct.

Comment: @Franz - You solved the problem. Thanks

Comment: I'm glad i helped you. You can also consider the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly use `where` before group by or after.

```
$destination = Trip::select('destination')
      ->selectRaw('COUNT(*) AS count')
      ->where('client_id', $userClientId)
      ->groupBy('destination')
      ->orderByDesc('count')
      ->limit(5)
      ->get();
```